# Getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in option.php" after updating a cache plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, cache

I updated "W3 Total Cache Plugin" and later the error below appeared:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1117

Any help?

Comment: What's the cache plugin? Also check it's compatibility with your wordpress version. Try upgrading wordpress to the latest version. But please have a proper backup first.

Comment: Updated "W3 Total Cache Plugin".  I'm using latest version of Wordpress already.

Comment: If you disable the plug-in (rename its folder over FTP), does the issue go away?

Comment: @inspirednz, How do I disable the plugin via the cpanel?

Comment: @J.Okwy: I gather you've since figured it out. I am glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 5):

I solved deleting the w3tc cache plugin from ftp

Comment: Thanks all. Deleting the plugin solved the problem. Site back up.